# how use parent Selecltor css3 crossbrowser

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to select the a element that is a parent .........................

i have aClass and cClass.. aClass is parent and cClass is child Class..

```
 <div class="a">
  <div class="c">mgmg</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="c">mgmg</div>
</div>

<div class="a">

</div>

<div class="a">
   <div class="c">mgmg</div>
</div>
```

//how use parent select csscode

```
.a < .c{

       border:1px solid red;
       color:red;
       background-color:green;
 }
```

Comment: there aren't any [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3639582)

Comment: This is the second time I've seen someone on here use `<` claiming it's "the CSS parent selector" and asking why it's not working. Where are they getting this from?

Comment: @BoltClock it was suggested as a way to make a parent selector but not accepted

Comment: @Dreamwalker: *Exactly.* I'm baffled as to how people take that to mean that it is valid and *should* work.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in CSS alone. CSS can only traverse down the DOM.

An alternative is to use javascript to find all your `.c` elements and find their parent `.a`, if it exists.